# Android studio 3.1.3 download kotlin-plug fail

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, plug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIFro.png)

Android studio 3.1.3 use kotlin-plug v'1.2.60, always Connection refused: connect.
What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Check your internet. *Connection refused* means the error is in your network connection.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?